# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'

Tags: python, keras

Собственно говоря, пытался импортировать библиотеки:

```
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 %matplotlib inline
 from collections import Counter 
 from keras.datasets import cifar10
```

Выводит ошибку: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'

p.s. и в pip'e и в самом jupyter'e установил и keras.datasets, и tensorflow

Comment: Вы установили `keras.datasets` не устанавливая `keras`?

Comment: Сам keras тоже установил

Comment: похоже `keras` установлен криво - попробуйте переустановить

Answer (score 2):

Пропишите в консоли

pip install keras

Comment: Лол, у меня jupyter не детектил, что я устанавливал и keras, и tf. Спасибо